# is_home not working in wordpress when using templates

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a div of services (full width) which I only want to display on the home page of my Wordpress site. I have used the conditional tag `if(is_home())` and it is working fine. But when I added a new template this division is showing up in the template page, too. I tried using:

```
(if(is_home())&&(!is_page_template('blog.php'))
```

...but unfortunately it is not working. I have also tried it using `ID` and `slug`, and yet still this particular `div` is coming in the template.

I some how want this `div` to show up only on the homepage. You can see the services div [here](http://geoiqdesign.com/). The same is being displayed [here](http://geoiqdesign.com/blog/), but not in other inner pages.

Comment: It should be if(is_home()) not if(is_home), right?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home

Comment: Yes Vincent. i have tried if(is_home()) only. its working fine. the division is only showing up in the homepage, not in the inner pages except the template page

Comment: Try Dipak answer, I'm sure that will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Try `if( is_home() && (!is_page_template('blog.php') )`

Comment: Use `Blog.php` instead `blog.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is_front_page()` instead.

[See Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

Comment: i have tried this too. my home page is not a static page. its the default index.php .so i don't think this will work. it would have obviously worked if it was a static home page which i have set form my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
<?php if (is_home()) : ?>
    // yes, home page
<?php else : ?>
    //no, not home page
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

`if(is_home() && !is_page_template('blog.php'))`

Everything Should be in one condition

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with any of the following conditional tags

```
if( is_home() && !is_page_template( 'page-  template-Blog-php' ) ) {

 // service div here

 }
```

Note: If you are using template in any folder you need to give folder path too.
For example: If you are placing all the templates in 'templates' folder your code will be:

```
 if( is_home() && !is_page_template(    'templates/page-template-Blog-php' ) ) {

 // service div here

 }
```

or you can try following code:

```
 if( is_home() || is_front_page()  ) {

 // service div here

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Braces wrongly placed:

```
if( (is_home()) && (!is_page_template('blog.php')) )
```